Confusion regarding disconnected graph
I am learning graph data structure and want to understand how to handle this scenario. I have multiple directed graphs inside a .NET C# program like so:
C<-A->B<-D     E->F
Here A points to B and C, D points to B and E points to F.
Visually I can see that there are 2 graphs, (A,B,C,D) & (E,F). But D points to B and is kind of isolated. Will D be considered a third graph like (A,B,C) & (D) & (E,F)?
I am asking because some graph traversals codes online are displaying D as a separate graph, however it is connected to B. I understand that it depends on the individual requirements and how one wants to display/use it. But I want to understand ideally how this scenario should be treated?
Please help me with my confusion. Thanks a lot.
It is a conceptual problem, and I am trying to understand it. I have tried searching online but I am getting mixed results. I need technical help to understand how to best handle this situation.

Will D be considered a third graph no, it's connected. It's no different than C.  codes online are displaying D as a separate graph That sounds like a bug. Do you have any link to algorithms that treat D as separate?

Are those arrows indicating DIRECTED or UNDIRECTED connections? You say that D is kind of "isolated". Why?

This isn't a technical issue. We can't guess what you've read or what code you run. ABCDE is one graph. It has 2 starting points, so maybe you tried something meant to find the largest graph.

@PanagiotisKanavos I have the code generated by ChatGPT. If you want I can share it.

@Idle_Mind The arrows indicate directed graph. I say D is kind of isolated because D cannot be reached from any other nodes, D needs to be traversed specifically as a starting point.

Random code generators don't produce logical code. They just produce strings that appear statistically related in the training data or with the words in your question. They have absolutely no understanding of either the training data or your question

@Wild-Programmer we can't guess what some truly random code did. Instead of using ChatGPT, read about graphs and algorithms and try real code. You can find NuGet packages for graph processing, or real articles and books describing how to detect graphs, find the longest or shortest unidirectional graph, find all possible graphs in a set etc

"I say D is kind of isolated because D cannot be reached from any other nodes, D needs to be traversed specifically as a starting point." Using that logic, A and E should be "isolated" as well because they cannot be reached from any other nodes since you said it is a directed graph. D is still connected to other nodes so it is not isolated as you say.


Visually I can see that there are 2 graphs, (A,B,C,D) & (E,F). But D points to B and is kind of isolated. Will D be considered a third graph like (A,B,C) & (D) & (E,F)?

No, D is still part of the same graph as ABCD. See wikipedia for examples of directed graph containing such nodes.
From a practical point of view it depends on what you want to do. If the goal is some kind of path finding you rarely need to consider if nodes are part of the same graph or not, most path finding algorithms work the same either way.
If the goal is to do some kind of segmentation it might be easiest to convert the graph to a undirected graph first.
